# Deserializar JSON com Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando fazer um deserialize, para criar uma lista com o conteudo desse JSON. Porém, tudo chega pra a lista como `null`. Vou deixar abaixo o que consegui até agora.

Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "A": "323",
            "B": "919",
            "C": "teste"
        },
        {
            "A": "325",
            "B": "919",
            "C": "testando"
        },
        {
            "A": "453",
            "B": "919",
            "C": "ola mundo"
        }
    ],
    "time": {
        "start": 1573048358.63732,
        "finish": 1573048358.673811,
        "duration": 0.036490917205810547,
        "processing": 0.0077030658721923828,
        "date_start": "2019-11-06T16:52:38+03:00",
        "date_finish": "2019-11-06T16:52:38+03:00"
    }
}
```

**Controlador**:

```
// RECEBE OS PRODUTOS DO NEGOCIO
var json = await http.GetStringAsync("CAMINHO DO JSON");
var produto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Empresa.Produto>(json);

return produto.ID;
```

**Classe**:

```
public class Empresa

{
    public class Produto
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**// RESOLVIDO! //**

A única mudança no código que fiz, foi na estrutra de classes, que com a alteração passou a ser:

```
public class Empresa
    {
        public class Produto
        {
            public List<result_classe> result { get; set; }

            public class result_classe
            {
                public string A { get; set; }
                public string B { get; set; }
                public string C { get; set; }
            }
        }
    }
```